# Controlling applications (sox)

Tags: ruby, shell, pipe, sox

When I call sox from Ruby using `exec` within my application, the command prompt does not let me return to my application until the selected file has completed playing.

If I use `IO.popen`, once I launched it, I loose control of the process.

I attempted to run the process with `pipe`, but the results to a file and return control to Ruby using the following command:

```
play '01\ -\ Planet\ Telex.mp3' > results.txt 2>&1 &
```

Sox uses the "I'm now a background process" command to pause itself, so as soon as the command above command runs, playback halts.

Maybe the solution would be to spawn a different shell from Ruby and operate the process inside of that. Does anyone have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "loose control of the process", because `IO.popen` should do exactly what you want: spawn a subprocess and give you access to the input/output.

Here is an example of using it to send input to `sed` and then read the result:

```
IO.popen(["sed", "-e", "s/^/foo/"], "r+") do |f|
  f.puts "bar"
  f.close_write
  puts f.gets
end
# foobar
```

If you want separate output/error streams, you can use [`popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

Comment: OK, that;s great, but how, while I am inside this `do` loop may I continue with other operations. I believe this has become more of a question about software design architecture.